# Restricting app store purchases to one per registered device. Is it possible?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am working on a application which has a more peculiar requirement. Basically it is something which is not targeted at end users but at a system integrator who will embed an iPad into a larger system and sell it to an end user as a whole.

However, the problem I'm facing is that the system integrators could simply purchase the app once and then keep cloning thousands of iPads from a single iTunes account, my company would not get any revenue from this.

Is there any way around this. I've looked at in app purchases but according to the guidelines I'm supposed to give in app purchase restore functionality so I guess if I don't the app won't get approved.

I could use external authentication servers I guess, but that may be viewed as circumventing the app store.

I've loked at the volume B2B stuff but I'm not quite clear on how that works or if it would help me in this case.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: also to clarify I'm logging for a "legitimate" way to solve this, that would have Apples' "blessing", don't want to jailbreak etc.

Comment: I wonder if your app will make it to the app store. Sounds like the app is only useful for your client. Your client should try to get a Enterprise account (if they sell thousands of iPads they can get one) and they should pay you directly. Clearly your client can't register thousands of iTunes accounts ;-)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: Indeed -- if the application is "not targeted at end users" then it will probably be rejected from the iOS App Store.

Comment: the system integrators are not "my clients" they are builders of a various systems (sorry I can't really be more specific) and the app is a generic tool to create a user interface. So it's not really specific. We are basically developing a tool for system integrators (and there are lots of them) to use in their systems. So from out perspective the system integrator is the end user, who will be on selling the whole system to their clients.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked an application can only be installed on five devices, and then the other ones simply refuse to install the application.

If this system integrator managed to circumvent this, it's he who is breaking the App Store rules.

Comment: I've heard this too someplace but have not been able to find any solid confirmation @Apple

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the App Store mechanisms as you described (you can't change iTunes). In-App purchases of non-consumable items must include a restore option so the user can restore it on all his devices even if it's thousands (this also for subscriptions etc). If you won't enable that you would be rejected.

You can think you can send the Device-ID for each device that purchase the item and have control over that(or any information) but apple would simply reject your app because it's forbidden to send device-ID.

If your service is online you can simply use some kind of tokens created on your servers which would be given to each client (from some kind of private key), This way you must be connected to each purchased item (only those would contact your servers and you would grant access).
Security wise you must consider leaving some of the functionality on your server side. This is not illegal same as you can't access Facebook without username& password.

And now for **the easy way**, Define your service as consumable item for in-App purchase(if you can). What does it mean? Lets say you are selling a special feature like "Ad-Free" you can sell credits that would be consumed with each app open or any other process you have in mind, You can even set this credit to 1 million for 0.99$ (so the user never gets to that) but still the consumer would have to buy it again and again for each device and it would be absolutely legal by Apple. Pay attention that the problem would be on the consumer side such as that if user have deleted his app you should find a way to help him or refund him on next buy. Also, If you can and would use this method pay attention to save those credits on the restored folder on the device, so if the user would upgrade or restore the device he would still have the credits he bought.

Pay attention that if you are going to use in-App there are lots of methods to steal this content on jailbroken devices and you must use your own server to check the buying process (according to Apple).

Another important thing is that the app without the in-App purchase must have some value to the user.